# ¿Cómo usar variable con $_POST[]?

Tags: php, javascript

Tengo el siguiente código html, donde paso datos seleccionados desde dos `select`:

```
<body>
    <h1></h1>

    <form action="valor.php" method="post">
        <div>
            <label></label>
            <br>
            <select id="caja1" name="caja1"></select>
        </div>

        <div>
            <label></label>
            <br>
            <select id="caja2" name="caja2"></select>
        </div>

        <div>
            <input type="submit" name="Mostrar" value="Mostrar">
        </div>
    </form>

    <div id="datos"></div>

</body>
```

Una vez doy al boton `Mostrar` almaceno los datos seleccionados, y los paso a las variables $seleccion1 = $_POST['caja1'] y $seleccion2 = $_POST['caja2'].

Quisiera usar esos datos en una funcion como esta:

```
$(document).on('click', '#caja_', function(){

    var valor = $(this).val();

    if (valor != "") {
        buscar_datos(valor);
    }else{
        buscar_datos();
    }
});
```

En donde '#caja_' debiese ser la variable "$seleccion1" o `$POST[caja1]`, ¿cómo debo hacerlo si el archivo donde tengo el metodo es tipo javascript?

Comment: Edita la pregunta para agregar el código de `buscar_datos()` y saber lo que quieres hacer realmente.

Answer (score 0):

Si deseas que la búsqueda se actualice en cada cambio de seleccion:

```
$("select").on('change', function(){
    buscar_datos();
});
```

Puedes enviar directamente el formulario en la llamada a `buscar_datos()`. Equivale a presionar el boton "Mostrar".

```
function buscar_datos(){
   $("form").submit();
}
```

Luego en el archivo php recibira los datos en $_POST. Puedes chequear si el valor no es vacio para agregarlos a la consulta y filtrar

```
$seleccion1 = $_POST['caja1'];
$seleccion2 = $_POST['caja2'];
$sql="SELECT * from mitabla WHERE .... "
if ($seleccion1!=""){
  $sql.=" AND campo1='$seleccion1'";
}
if ($seleccion2!=""){
  $sql.=" AND campo2='$seleccion2'";
}
// Ejecutar $sql filtrada
```

Para evitar usar los selectores `select`, `form` es mejor definir un `id` para elementos individuales y `class` para grupos de elementos.

```
<form id="myform" .. >
<select class="selector" id="caja1" .. >
<select class="selector" id="caja2" .. >
```

Luego usar

```
$("#myform").submit();
$(".selector").on('change', ... );
```

Comment: Envío los datos del formulario a una pagina PHP, en la pagina muestro una tabla que extraigo de MySQL, y quiero que el valor de la selección filtre esta tabla, entonces el valor llega en forma de POST.